# A questions about "on hold" status of a question and about "closed" status

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have a question that´s been put "on hold". And I have some questions.

> Who can see that this question is "on hold"? Can that see all users of the site or even some people who browse this site "from the outside", that, is even people who are not registered users of the site?
>
> Who can see by whom was this question put "on hold", that is, who can see who are the users who put this question "on hold"?
>
> And, who can see who gave a reason for putting that question "on hold"? Is it also visible by everyone on the site?
>
> And, the same three questions for the "closed" status.

**Edit**: Also, three more questions, closely related:

> Can the names of the people who put some question "on hold" or closed it be hidden? If there is a way to hide the names, would that do more good for almost everyone?

I do not see a particular good reason why it is good that I see the names of the people who put some of my questions "on hold" or closed them, if that part would be anonymous, I would have almost nothing against such a rule.

> So, I would like to know, why it is decided, from the people who are building the site, that the names are visible?

Comment: It is relatively easy to check how users who are not logged in see the question - simply view the site in incognito mode/private browsing. (You could also log out and then log in again - but that's quite a hassle.)

Comment: Regarding the question why the close voters are displayed (which you added in the edit), you can check the discussions on Meta Stack Exchange: [What's the goal of listing the users that voted to close a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174183) and [Hide the names of the people who voted to close a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54895).